# unable to display anything other than directory listing

Tags: windows-xp, deployment, asp.net-mvc, iis, directory-listing

Okay i have what may seem a really easy to solve problem but i've been trying to solve it for days.

I'm trying to deploy a asp.net MVC2 application to a IIS 5.1 server running Windows XP Pro. (it's actually the default MVC2 app)
However when i deploy, the only thing i'm able to see is a Directory listing. I tried a lot of stuff but can't get it to display anything other than the directory listing.

hopefully i'm just a noob who forgot to add something, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that:

- The appropriate .NET Framework has been installed on the workstation.
- ASP.NET has been installed (if the .NET Framework was installed prior to IIS being installed, it won't be): [aspnet_regiis -i](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: i tried installing it, it installed succesfully but i still get the damn directory listing :(

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution, i had to add an extension to run mvcs:
http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html